# Windows 10 - Headphones / Headset Audio Volume

Tags: windows-10, audio, headphones

I had a strange issue - I was adjusting the volume for my Windows 10 desktop, and when I pressed the Down Volume in-line button on my Logitech H390 headphones, something weird happened:  The volume meter when from 0, to 99, as though it wrapped around and got lower than 0 volume.

After this, my maximum volume was wrong, as though the scale went from 0-100 to 0-30.  In otherwords, the volume meter (the black windows 10 meter that shows up) had 100 listed, but the volume was much lower.

I attempted all fixes I could find(such as Loudness equalization, driver correction, and so on,) but nothing fixed it.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

After some more troubleshooting, this appeared to be a bug of some sort in the Windows Audio service.

To fix:

1. Reboot the Windows Audio service
2. The volume should return to normal.

I would presume a system reboot would be the next step if that does not work, but it worked for me.

Hope this helps!